# Reg edit executable

Tags: string, registry, regedit

I have a simple question but just can't find the answer (perhaps looking for the wrong keywords).

I want to create a regedit that changes personal in the registery in this case "Personal"="\\.....\COMPUTERUSER$"

But I want to use a string in the rededit that looks for the local user automatically, so in this case COMPUTERUSER needs to be updated automatically to the current user of windows.

Anyone knows this? Thanks...

tried to look for the string online, unable to find it, not sure if it exists?